# Mutate object state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

```
<Mutation mutation={addUserQuery} variables={{
  username: "AuraDivitiae",
  firstname: "Michael",
  lastname: "Lee"
}}>
  {
    (addUser, data) => {
      count = count + 1
      console.log("render no:" + count);
      console.log(data)

      return (
        <div className="form">
          <form onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => { addUser(); resolve("Mutation function called!") }).
              then((prevData) => { console.log(prevData); console.log(data); })
          }}>
            <button type="submit">Add User</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }

  }
</Mutation>
```

Console Logs

```
    render no:1
    main.js:88 
{called: false, loading: false, data: undefined, error: undefined, client: DefaultClient}
```

**----------------Button clicked------------------------------------------**

```
    render no:2
    main.js:88 
{called: true, loading: true, data: undefined, error: undefined, client: DefaultClient}

    main.js:98 
Mutation function called!

    main.js:98 
{called: false, loading: false, data: undefined, error: undefined, client: DefaultClient}

    render no:3
    main.js:88 
{called: true, loading: false, data: {…}, error: undefined, client: DefaultClient}
```

From these logs, i can see that initially when the Mutate component mounts we get render no: 1.
When the button is clicked at the **line**, addUser() mutate function is called in a promise which resolves with "Mutation function called".
However in the logs it shows the mutate result object at main.js:88, this means its a re-render of the component.

My question is, does calling the mutate function update the state which re-renders the component? And was the control passed to the mutate function so that the component re-rendered before the promise could be resolved and thereafter used?
But after the re-render shouldn't the data show called?

Comment: Anyone, please!